# How to initialize the static member for template with function pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, templates

```cpp
template <typename X, typename Y, Y X::*Member>
struct util
{
   static const double shared_value;
};

template <typename X, typename Y, Y X::*Member>
const double util<X, Y, Y X::*Member>::shared_value = 1;   // This line cannot compile.
```

How to initialize the static member for template with function pointer as parameter? Thanks.

Comment: `const double util<X, Y, Member>::shared_value`

Comment: Do you want to share a common value independent on type? This should not be done using templates since the value gets copied.

Comment: Thanks "Simple"! It is so simple...It wastes me an hour...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in C++11 you can do

```
template <typename X, typename Y, Y X::*Member>
struct util
{
   static constexpr double shared_value = 1;
};
```

Comment: How about without C++11 and C++0x? Thx.